# AWS ELB HTTPS Redirect Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-elb

I'd like to force https on a wordpress site. The site is on an was ec2 instance and is being pointed to via an ELB which is forwarding ports http on  80 and https on 443 which is assigned to my certificate.

When i go to my site at https://mysite the https site works. But i'd like to redirect all http to https. I've implemented the HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto as suggested but the site doesn't forward. What am i missing?! Thanks

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Remove the `=` before `http`?